# SQL server SET variable not allowing option when using SELECT

Tags: sql-server

I have found some odd syntax behaviour around the use of OPTION on a SELECT statement when assigning values to local variables. It looks like OPTION is allowed when the statement starts with SELECT but if it's part of a SET command then it is disallowed.

```
DECLARE @var CHAR(1)

SET @var = (SELECT '1' OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 2312))

SET @var = (SELECT '1') OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 2312);

SELECT @var = '1' OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 2312)

SELECT @var
```

Pasting the above into SSMS shows both varieties of SET are disallowed but the SELECT version is allowed. I would like to know if my syntax on SET is wrong and what the correct use for OPTION would be, or if this is simply the behaviour and I need to use SELECT to set the variable.

Comment: Your syntax on `SET` is wrong. `OPTION` can be used only in a standalone `SELECT` statement, not one which is part of a `SET`. You can find [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189484.aspx) the full syntax supported by `SET`, including all of the options you can pass to it and its `SELECT`. Also, here are some more details on [**OPTION**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190322.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OPTION Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190322.aspx)

> This clause can be specified in the SELECT, DELETE, UPDATE and MERGE
>   statements.

Comment: Thank you! I was searching for use of SET in the documentation but I obviously needed to change that search for use of OPTION instead.